# What does "newreg" mean in the URL?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, stack-exchange

I just got an answer from a new (1 rep) user which linked me to another question with a `newreg` argument in the URL. What does that mean?

If I google that I find many hits on the Stack Exchange network, but nothing helpful.

Comment: Related (although this doesn't answer your *specific* question about `newreg`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120891/163863. In short, *we slap slugs onto links in places where we're looking for hard numbers about usage*.

Comment: @Matt great to know but that newreg is not listed there, as you already noted.

Comment: Probably tracking URLs from newly registered users...